# Connman does not seem to start a DHCP server

Tags: yocto, networkmanager, connman

I am creating a USB gadget with Yocto, which loads the gadget kernel modules and is recognized by my host as a network interface (`usb0`). On the gadget, I have `connman` installed and running. I am using the default configuration (no `/etc/connman/main.conf`), though I have tried to manually enable the gadget in `/var/lib/connman/settings`:

```
~# cat /var/lib/connman/settings
[global]
OfflineMode=false

[Gadget]
Enable=true
Tethering=true
```

However, when I try to get an IP from the host (with e.g. `dhcpcd usb0`), it does not seem to find a DHCP server, and I get an IPv4LL instead. The journalctl of my host looks like this:

```
avahi-daemon[812]: Registering new address record>
dhcpcd[875]: usb0: soliciting an IPv6 router
dhcpcd[875]: usb0: soliciting a DHCP lease
dhcpcd[875]: usb0: probing for an IPv4LL address
dhcpcd[875]: usb0: using IPv4LL address 169.254.1>
avahi-daemon[812]: Joining mDNS multicast group o>
avahi-daemon[812]: New relevant interface usb0.IP>
dhcpcd[875]: usb0: adding route to 169.254.0.0/16
avahi-daemon[812]: Registering new address record>
dhcpcd[875]: usb0: no IPv6 Routers available
```

Note that on the gadget, I created a service profile to give an IP to the `usb0` interface, which gets:

```
3: usb0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP8000> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast qlen 1000
    link/ether 66:7e:25:f1:3d:cf brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 10.42.0.2/24 brd 10.42.0.255 scope global usb0
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::647e:25ff:fef1:3dcf/64 scope link 
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
```

This is the service config:

```
[service_gadget]
Type = gadget
IPv4 = 10.42.0.2/255.255.255.0/10.42.0.1
```

What could I be missing for Connman to start a DHCP server and successfully assign an IP to the host `usb0` interface when it asks for one?

Comment: BTW there is really something I don't get: `yocto`, `connman` and `networkmanager` do exist as tags on stackoverflow, but still everytime I ask a question about them, it gets downvoted. Though I see tons of questions about configuring nginx and similar that are not directly about programming, and those are not downvoted/closed. Is that because nginx is more used by developers, and yocto is not? In that case, shouldn't the `yocto` tag be removed completely from SO? And what about all the questions about using `git` or `docker` in CLI?